# For an app with broken clipboard behavior, can I route the paste buffer as though it were coming from the keyboard in macOS Monterey?

Tags: macos, keyboard, copy-paste

I have a remote connection to a VM that is a bit of a problem.

If I want to paste text into the remote machine, I'm just boned - the software that is hosting the connection is passing the <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> (or <kbd>^</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>) to the remote machine (a Windows box, and I'm using macOS Monterey) instead of trapping it and realizing that I want to pass the paste buffer through.

The remote machine has no net connection, except through this VM connection, so I can't use something like GitHub, Google Docs, or Dropbox as a go-between.

I realize that this is a horrific longshot, given how complex and arcane keyboards and their drivers are (and the fact that I'm bridging the keyboard across to another OS.)

Is there any way to get my local machine to replay the contents of the paste buffer though the keyboard interface?